# Z-Index NOT working on Angular's Material Dialog

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Bug:

Z-Index NOT working on Material Dialog

What is the expected behavior?

Z-Index should work on Material Dialog or Dialog should be on top of everything else.

What is the current behavior?

Material Dialog gets covered by select's options that are below.

What are the steps to reproduce?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsa8kr-rkss7t?file=app/dialog-overview-example.html

1. Type text.
2. Select dropdown.

Screenshots: https://postimg.cc/gallery/2i3tc2sbc/

Is there anything else we should know?

Tried CSS fixes:

```
.modal__content,dialog-layout,mat-dialog-container,.mat-dialog-container,#cdk-overlay-0,.cdk-overlay-pane {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

NONE of that worked.

Answer (score 10):

The class holding the matdialog overlay is **cdk-overlay-container**

Add this code to your style.css

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: It solved my problem when I added ::ng-deep, Why is that?

Comment: @mr.Nobody `::ng-deep` essentially pierces the DOM structure straight down to your desired element to override a component's style. However, this practice messes with Angular's encapsulation _(keeping a child component's styles only within its parent element)_, resulting in styles that are affected by `::ng-deep` to be passed around your application and disrupt your other styles. You can try to set the overlay's styles within your main .css file.

Answer (score 3):

The `<select>` element is an interactive content element in HTML. It and behaves like a right click context menu and is rendered above all document elements.

In your case, when you click on select after entering your name in the field, the following things happen in sequence:

1. Blur event on the textbox is called and dialog opens.
2. Select menu opens.

So, according the sequence, what is happening is correct i.e. the dialog is opening first and then the select, so the select is above dialog which is correct.

But of course the interface does not seems good when this happens so there is a workaround, i.e. hide the select when the dialog opens and then show it again after lets say 0.1 seconds. As the select hides, its menu will hide with it.

I have implemented it for you. Please have a look at this Stackblitz: [Select closing on dialog open](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsa8kr-wf74nn?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much for your help! Highly appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this is the correct answer, kindly accept this answer as the best answer so other users will give it a read.

Comment: @NabilShahid what if i need its z-index differently on different elements like mat-menu goes behind my fixed header and mat-dialog above my fixed header but i can't do that both used cdk-overlay-container so i cant set its index separately.